# Exporting Video from Libreoffice Presentation?

Tags: windows-7, libreoffice-impress

I had downloaded a Microsoft Powerpoint presentation, opening up the file in Libreoffice 4. I have a video on a slide I would like to save as an individual file, which looks like a tricky situation. I tried right clicking on the thumbnail on the slide in edit mode, selecting **"Save Graphic..."**, but only Photo formats were available. Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a `.pptx` you can apparently just open it with WinZip and extract the video.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091628/how-to-export-movie-from-powerpoint-2010/5112922#5112922